# Apply Nested list comprehension in a function

Tags: python-2.7, list, for-loop

How do I apply nested list comprehension, on the nested for loop in addCoordinate function in my program, without affecting the output.  I have gotten it to print a maze in the format as achieved in output, but I wish to make my entire program more compact and improve its time complexity.

```
from itertools import product
class Maze:
    mazeboard, x1, y1, list = [], 0, 0, []

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Constructor - You may modify this, but please do not add any extra parameters
        """

    def addCoordinate(self, x, y, blockType):
        #print self.x1
        if self.x1 < x :
            self.x1 = x
        if self.y1 < y:
            self.y1 = y
        if  len(self.mazeboard) <= self.x1 or  len(self.mazeboard) <= self.y1:
            modified_board = [[1 for a in range(self.x1 + 1)] for b in range(self.y1 + 1)]
            for a in range(len(self.mazeboard)):
                for b in range(len(self.mazeboard[a])):
                    modified_board[a][b] = self.mazeboard[a][b]
            self.mazeboard = modified_board
        self.mazeboard[y][x] = blockType

    def printMaze(self):
        for a in range(self.x1 + 1):
            for b in range(self.y1 + 1):
                if self.mazeboard[a][b] == 0:
                    print " ",
                else:
                    print "*",
            print ""


def mazeTest():
    myMaze = Maze()
    myMaze.addCoordinate(1, 0, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(1, 1, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 1, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(1, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(2, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(3, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(6, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 3, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 3, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 4, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 4, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(3, 5, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 5, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 5, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(1, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(2, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(3, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(6, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(5, 7, 0)
    myMaze.printMaze()
mazeTest()
```

Output for my program is:

```
*   * * * * * * 
*   * * * * *   
*         *     
* * * *   * *   
* * * *   * *   
* * *     * *   
*         *     
* * * * *   * *
```

Comment: Please, add a precise question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could improve things in a few different ways:

1. Create a list of coordinates rather than calling `addCoordinate()` multiple times.
2. Improve your maze printing by converting your maze with a dictionary into `*` and  chars and then joining it all together into a single printable string.
3. Using `product` to copy across your old `mazeboard` into your updated one.

For example:

```
from itertools import product

class Maze:
    mazeboard, x1, y1 = [], 0, 0

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Constructor - You may modify this, but please do not add any extra parameters
        """

    def addCoordinate(self, x, y, blockType):
        if self.x1 < x :
            self.x1 = x
        if self.y1 < y:
            self.y1 = y
        if  len(self.mazeboard) <= self.x1 or len(self.mazeboard) <= self.y1:
            modified_board = [[1 for a in range(self.x1 + 1)] for b in range(self.y1 + 1)]
            if len(self.mazeboard):
                for a, b in product(range(len(self.mazeboard)), range(len(self.mazeboard[0]))):
                    modified_board[a][b] = self.mazeboard[a][b]            

            self.mazeboard = modified_board
        self.mazeboard[y][x] = blockType

    def printMaze(self):
        print '\n'.join(' '.join(map({1:'*', 0:' '}.get, row)) for row in self.mazeboard)


def mazeTest():
    myMaze = Maze()

    coords = [
        (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (7, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0), (2, 2, 0), 
        (3, 2, 0), (4, 2, 0), (6, 2, 0), (7, 2, 0), (4, 3, 0), (7, 3, 0), 
        (4, 4, 0), (7, 4, 0), (3, 5, 0), (4, 5, 0), (7, 5, 0), (1, 6, 0), 
        (2, 6, 0), (3, 6, 0), (4, 6, 0), (6, 6, 0), (7, 6, 0), (5, 7, 0)]

    for coord in coords:
        myMaze.addCoordinate(*coord)

    myMaze.printMaze()

mazeTest()
```